# Find last row in column next to selected cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have to delete large sections of rows often, I can unfortunately not write any macros in the excel file itself. So I made another excel file that hold the macros that I need. That also means that the range is variable.

I now need to find a way to delete all rows that contain a "0" in the column next to my selected cell. After that I need to fill in the date and drag down my selected cell until the last row ([please see illustration below).
[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE7Og.png)

so far I have this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    Dim RngSelected As Range
    Dim dtToday As String
    dtToday = Format(Date, "yymmdd")      
       
    Set RngSelected = Application.InputBox(Title:="Please select a range", Prompt:="Select range", Type:=8)    
    
    For Each cell In RngSelected
        cell.Value = dtToday 
    Next    
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ColC As Long

    ColC = RngSelected.Column - 1 'this part seems to identify the correct column (as column number)
    
    LastRow = Range(ColC & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'this part does not work at the moment 

    RngSelected.AutoFill Destination:=Range(RngSelected & ":" & RngSelected.Column & LastRow) ' this also does not work currently    
End Sub
```

Any suggestions would be much apricated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine this data
[image]

And the following code

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DoSomeStuff()
    
    ' get selection so we know where to start
    Dim SelRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set SelRng = Application.InputBox(Title:="Please select a range", Prompt:="Select range", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If SelRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' find out which sheet we are working with
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = SelRng.Parent
    
    ' get last used row left of the selection
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, SelRng.Column - 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' get the data range left of the selection
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Set DataRange = SelRng.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).Resize(LastRow - SelRng.Row + 1)
    
    
    ' here we collect all rows that will be deleted
    Dim RowsToDelete As Range
    
    ' loop through all cells in the data range
    Dim Cell As Variant
    For Each Cell In DataRange.Cells
        ' if value is zero add the row to RowsToDelete
        If Cell.Value = 0 Then
            If RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
                Set RowsToDelete = Cell.EntireRow
            Else
                Set RowsToDelete = Application.Union(RowsToDelete, Cell.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell
    
    ' if RowsToDelete were found then delete them
    If Not RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
        RowsToDelete.Delete
    End If
    
    ' get again the last used row (because we deleted rows it's less)
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, SelRng.Column - 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' write the numeric date into the first cell
    SelRng.Value = Now()
    SelRng.NumberFormat = "YYMMDD" 'format the date
    
    ' fill down
    SelRng.AutoFill ws.Range(SelRng, ws.Cells(LastRow, SelRng.Column))
End Sub
```

will turn it into
[image]

I highly recommend never to use `dtToday = Format(Date, "yymmdd")` to write a date into a cell, because `Format` will return a `String` which is a text looking like a date. But this is not a date anymore so you cannot calculate with it. **Always** use a numeric date like `SelRng.Value = Now()` or `Date()` and then format it using `NumberFormat`. This way it stays a numeric date that you can calculate with and you can easly change the format whenever needed.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly 
And thank you for the advice about the format, I will keep it in mind.